# Intellij: how to open a library java source and set a breakpoint for debugging?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, libraries, breakpoints

Intellij: how to open a library java source and set a breakpoint for debugging?

From a stacktrace, we know where to set a breakpoint. Right now, we have to step
into one lib java source at a time during debug and it takes a long time to get to the source line we are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can navigate to any file using the [Search Everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html) feature (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) or `Navigate` | `File` / `Class` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

If you change the scope to **Project and Libraries**, this will also navigate to the library classes where you can set the breakpoints.

[image: Project and Libraries]